# How do I link to two stylesheets with ASP.Net MVC 3?

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc-3, twitter-bootstrap

I'd like to use [Bootstrap from Twitter](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/) in my ASP.Net MVC 3 application. I downloaded bootstrap.css and added it to my project in the Content folder. I opened _Layout.cshtml and added a link to the file:

```
<head>
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Site.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/bootstrap.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

When I run the application no stylesheet is applied. How do I reference both Site.css and bootstrap.css from my _Layout.cshtml file?

Comment: What you have should work. If you open the site in Firebug and check the Net tab, are all the files loading?

Comment: Yes, the Firebug Net tab shows both loading. I reversed the order of the two link lines then everything worked. If Site.css is before bootstrap.css only bootstrap is applied (which I didn't realize at first). Reverse the order and both work. Strange.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**I think the issue here is the inheritance, cascade and specificity CSS.** Bear in mind that Twitter's Bootstrap resets all styles.

> 'If Site.css is before bootstrap.css only bootstrap is applied (which I didn't realize at first). Reverse the order and both work. Strange'

Actually, this makes complete sense. `Site.css` is loaded with all it's style declarations and immediately afterwards `Bootstrap.css` is loaded which resets most(if not all styles) thus declarations within `Bootstrap.css` will be applied. It only appears that both work probably because `Bootstrap.css` might not have a defined style or `Site.css` has very specific style defined using html ids or classes.

Reverse the order (with `Bootstrap.css` first), you are now resetting all styles first and then other styles are being applied. Since `Site.css` is loaded second, the styles defined therein will be applied to your site.

For your own interest, try to define an inline style within your html doc that has been defined within both 'Site.css' and 'Bootstrap.css', and see how the style gets applied by adding/removing the style definition.

I tried finding a good supporting explanation for CSS cascading, and the best graphic and simple explanation I found was [this](http://www.communitymx.com/content/article.cfm?page=2&cid=2795D) which notes

> *If selectors within external and embedded style sheets conflict but
>   have the same specificity, the final tie-breaker is based on the order
>   of apperance of the rules: the rule declared later wins. This applies
>   not only to the order of rules within a single sheet, but also to the
>   order that the sheets are linked, imported or embedded in the head of
>   the (X)HTML page.*

Answer (score -1):

You can copy and paste the CSS from the bootstrap file into your single .css file in order to cut down on the HTTP requests.

Just place all the bootstrap code at the very beginning and then your personal CSS following it, for organizational purposes.

---

However what you've done should work. Can you post an example on JSFiddle of what your markup looks like?

For more information see:

http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/present/styles.html#h-14.3

Comment: Thanks. I haven't tried JSFiddle but the Firebug Net tab shows both loading. I reversed the order of the two link lines then everything worked. If Site.css is before bootstrap.css only bootstrap is applied (which I didn't realize at first). Reverse the order and both work. Strange.

Comment: >> You can copy and paste the CSS from the bootstrap file into your single .css file in order to cut down on the HTTP requests. <<
Don't do this by hand, use a tool like squishit that will bundle/minify scripts http://www.codethinked.com/squishit-the-friendly-aspnet-javascript-and-css-squisher